# Zend Barcode Library Not Working with codeigniter in Live Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter-3, barcode

I am using zend library from [here](https://github.com/desta88/Codeigniter-Barcode-Generator-Zend-Library)

My code:
Invoice Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Invoice extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('InvoiceModel');
        $this->load->library('zend');
        $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    }
    public function index()
    {

        $code = uniqid();
        $rendererOptions = array('imageType'          =>'png');
        $file= Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$code), $rendererOptions);
        imagepng($file,"assets/barcode/{$code}.png");
        $data['barcode'] = $code;
        $this->load->view('InvoiceView', $data);

        }
    }
}
?>
```

In InvoiceView

```
<img class=" barcode" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/barcode/'.$barcode.'.png'?>">
```

It is working fine in **localhost**, But not working in **live server**.

Answer (score 0):

You make a small change in Zend.php library file following as:

`class CI_Zend`  change to `class Zend`

Nothing else. Enjoy it :)